# Clustered queues only available when owned by specific node

Tags: msmq, windows-server-2008-r2, failover

We've set up a Windows Failover Cluster (Windows 2008R2) with two nodes (CL-01 and CL-02) and MSMQ service (CL-MQ). Everything seems to work while the cluster resource is owned by CL-01, however when we fail it over to CL-02, the queues are not returned when making the call `[System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("cl-mq")`. This works as expected in our QA environment, so it seems some configuration is off.

Interestingly, the queues are visible in the Computer management console when launched from the Failover Cluster Manager ("Manage MSMQ" button). Any ideas on what could be the error? The calls are made from the cluster nodes, so there is no firewall involved. The account making the calls is local administrator on both nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/18/clustering-msmq-applications-rule-1.aspx ?

What's the storage location used by clustered MSMQ?